# 2xRaspberry Pi nRF24L01 not connecting

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am new to Stackoverflow. I have searched for answer, but didn't find anything.

I have two Raspberry Pi 2B+, each with nRF24l01 connected. I found few libraries to make this connect, only one give any results, but not connections. This one: [Github BLavery](https://github.com/BLavery/lib_nrf24)

I write script to send and to recv:

send.py:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from lib_nrf24 import NRF24
import time
import spidev

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

pipes = [[0xe7, 0xe7, 0xe7, 0xe7, 0xe7], [0xc2, 0xc2, 0xc2, 0xc2, 0xc2]]

radio = NRF24(GPIO, spidev.SpiDev())
radio.begin(0, 17)
radio.setPayloadSize(32)
radio.setChannel(0x60)

radio.setDataRate(NRF24.BR_2MBPS)
radio.setPALevel(NRF24.PA_MIN)
radio.setAutoAck(True)
radio.enableDynamicPayloads()
radio.enableAckPayload()

radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[1])
radio.printDetails()

while True:
    message = list("Hello World")
    radio.write(message)
    print("We sent the message of {}".format(message))

    # Check if it returned a ackPL
    if radio.isAckPayloadAvailable():
        returnedPL = []
        radio.read(returnedPL, radio.getDynamicPayloadSize())
        print("Our returned payload was {}".format(returnedPL))
    else:
        print("No payload received")
    time.sleep(1)
```

recv.py:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from lib_nrf24 import NRF24
import time
import spidev

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

pipes = [[0xe7, 0xe7, 0xe7, 0xe7, 0xe7], [0xc2, 0xc2, 0xc2, 0xc2, 0xc2]]

radio = NRF24(GPIO, spidev.SpiDev())
radio.begin(0, 17)
radio.setPayloadSize(32)
radio.setChannel(0x60)

radio.setDataRate(NRF24.BR_2MBPS)
radio.setPAlevel(NRF24.PA_MIN)
radio.setAutoAck(True)
radio.enableDynamicPayloads()
radio.enableAckPayload()

radio.openReadingPipe(1, pipes[1])
radio.printDetails()

radio.startListening()

while True:
    ackPL = [1]
    while not radio.available (0):
        time.sleep(1/100)

    receivedMessage = []
    radio.read(receivedMessage, radio.getDynamicPayloadSize())
    print("Received: {}".format(receivedMessage))

    print("Translating the receivedMessage into unicode characters...")
    string = ""
    for n in receivedMessage:
        # Decode into standard i=unicode set
        if (n >=32 and n <= 126):
            string += chr(n)
    print(string)

    radio.writeAckPayload(1, ackPL, len(ackPL))
    print("Loaded payload reply of {}".format(ackPL))
```

Everything seems to be alright, below are code returned by both scripts:

send:

```
STATUS   = 0x03 RX_DR=0 TX_DS=0 MAX_RT=0 RX_P_NO=1 TX_FULL=1

RX_ADDR_P0-1     =
 0xf8f8f8f8f8 0xf8f8f8f8f8

RX_ADDR_P2-5     =
0xf8
0xf9
0xf9
0xf9

TX_ADDR      =
 0xf8f8f8f8f8

RX_PW_P0-6   =
0x0c
0x00
0x00
0x00
0x00
0x00

EN_AA        =
0x0f

EN_RXADDR    =
0x00

RF_CH        =
0x1c

RF_SETUP     =
0x00

CONFIG       =
0x03

DYNPD/FEATURE    =
0x03
0x01

Data Rate    = 1MBPS
Model        = nRF24L01
CRC Length   = Disabled
PA Power     = PA_MIN

We sent the message of ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']

No payload received
```

recv.py:

```
STATUS   = 0x03 RX_DR=0 TX_DS=0 MAX_RT=0 RX_P_NO=1 TX_FULL=1

RX_ADDR_P0-1     =
 0xf8f8f8f8f8 0xf8f8f8f8f8

RX_ADDR_P2-5     =
0xf8
0xf9
0xf9
0xf9

TX_ADDR      =
 0xf8f8f8f8f8

RX_PW_P0-6   =
0x0c
0x0c
0x00
0x00
0x00
0x00

EN_AA        =
0x0f

EN_RXADDR    =
0x00

RF_CH        =
0x1c

RF_SETUP     =
0x00

CONFIG       =
0x03

DYNPD/FEATURE    =
0x03
0x01

Data Rate    = 1MBPS
Model        = nRF24L01
CRC Length   = Disabled
PA Power     = PA_MIN

Received: []

Translating the receivedMessage into unicode characters...

Loaded payload reply of [1]
```

I don't really understand why it won't connect one to other, 
Both have the same wiring:

nRF24L01-Raspberry Pi (Pin#)

- GND - GND (6)
- VCC - 3,3V (1)
- CE - GPIO17 (11)
- CSN - GPIO08(24)
- SCK - GPIO11 (23)
- MOSI - GPIO10 (19)
- MISO - GPIO25 (22)
- IRQ - unconnected

I need to send information from one RPi to second to control engine via PWM.

Can i ask for help